# How to get a DataCell value in aspxGridView?

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

How to get a data cell value in HtmlCommandCellPrepared event of aspxGridView?

I have datacolumn named `Issue` if text in that column is `RESOLVED` then I want the delete button to be visible in the `commandcolumn` else delete button will be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through [ASPxGridView - Hide / Show Custom Command Button / ASPxGridView.CustomButtonInitialize](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q438657)

You can do this as below:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CommandButtonInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewCommandButtonEventArgs e) {
    if (e.VisibleIndex == -1) return;

    switch (e.ButtonType) {
        case ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit:
            e.Visible = EditButtonVisibleCriteria((ASPxGridView)sender, e.VisibleIndex);
            break;
        case ColumnCommandButtonType.Delete:
            e.Visible = DeleteButtonVisibleCriteria((ASPxGridView)sender, e.VisibleIndex);
            break;
    }
}

private bool DeleteButtonVisibleCriteria(ASPxGridView grid, int visibleIndex) {
    object row = grid.GetRow(visibleIndex);
    return ((DataRowView)row)["ProductName"].ToString().Contains("b");
}
```

Refer this:
[ASPxGridView - How to specify the CommandButtons’ and Custom CommandButtons’ properties based on any custom criteria](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3028)